# Positioning images within trix wysiwyg editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

Is there a way to position images within the Rails 6 ActiveText Trix editor when writing content? If you upload an image, it is automatically placed in the middle of the page. I can change this in the CSS file, but when writing many "blogs", how can I position each image on the left or right within that particular blog on a live site? Each blog should have a potentially different layout.